# Pure sinewave cascaded H bridge multilevel inverter

Tags: capacitor, inverter

[image]
What is the function of the capacitor C1 in this inverter circuit?

Answer (score 1):

That is a DC-Link capacitor. It's to reduce ripple and voltage spikes. Generally you'll have a DC-Link capacitor and smaller ceramic decoupling capacitors. The ceramic decoupling capacitors should be placed close to the devices and will preform better at reducing voltage spikes than the bulk electrolytic especially in high dv/dt switching transitions.

Comment: How do i calculate the right value for a DC link capacitor as the one in the figure above, i would like to design an inverter but i do not know how to calculate the dc link capacitor value.

Comment: @RonnyAlfons it will depend on the amount of current being drawn from the DC Bus. To be honest, I don't do any calculations. I will pick an arbitrary value for bulk electrolytic capacitance and then arbitrary value for the decoupling capacitors. Then when I go to test the circuit, if I see high voltage spikes, I'll try adding more capacitance. If it looks good, then I'll try reducing capacitance to see at what point I start seeing voltage spikes beyond what I deem reasonable.

For the circuit above, I would start with the 220uF, 10uF Film and 10uF ceramic located close to the drain of Q1&Q4.